# Get URL of BrightCove video for download and Stream

Tags: android, video, rtmp, brightcove

I am creating an android app in which I want to play as well as download videos from BrightCove now the problem is BrightCove has its own player i.e. `com.brightcove.player.view.BrightcoveExoPlayerVideoView` Which I could not use. I have to play the video in Android Native MediaPlayer.

I have check all the docs and there they only provide some thing like this again and again

```
  EventEmitter eventEmitter = brightcoveVideoView.getEventEmitter();
    Catalog catalog = new Catalog(eventEmitter, getString(R.string.account), getString(R.string.policy));

    catalog.findVideoByID(getString(R.string.videoId), new VideoListener() {

      // Add the video found to the queue with add().
      // Start playback of the video with start().
      @Override
        public void onVideo(Video video) {
          brightcoveVideoView.add(video);
          brightcoveVideoView.start(); 
        }

      @Override
        public void onError(String s) {
          throw new RuntimeException(s);
        }
    });
```

How could I get the exact url for playing and downloading?

When search for a Video on BrightCove using servercalls/API_tester it returns some this

> {   "id": 1520880903001,   "name": "Space-Galaxy",   "adKeys": null,   "shortDescription": "Used as sample for Accessing Video Content with
>   the Media API -- DO NOT DELETE",   "longDescription": null,
>   "creationDate": "1332264917716",   "publishedDate": "1332264917716",
>   "lastModifiedDate": "1441607273772",   "linkURL":
>   "http://support.brightcove.com/en/docs/accessing-video-content-media-api",
>   "linkText": "Accessing Video Content with the Media API",   "tags": [
>       "newtag"   ],   "videoStillURL": "http://brightcove.vo.llnwd.net/e1/pd/57838016001/57838016001_1520916808001_vs-1520911645001.jpg?pubId=57838016001",
>   "thumbnailURL":
>   "http://brightcove.vo.llnwd.net/e1/pd/57838016001/57838016001_1520916809001_th-1520911645001.jpg?pubId=57838016001",
>   "referenceId": "1520880903001",   "length": 20000,   "economics":
>   "AD_SUPPORTED",   "playsTotal": 102,   "playsTrailingWeek": 0,
>   "FLVURL":
>   "rtmp://brightcove.fcod.llnwd.net/a500/e1/uds/rtmp/ondemand/&mp4:57838016001/57838016001_1520916807001_Space-Galaxy.mp4&1460095200000&a99dcabb0f88cdf8d21b3a5778da8e06",
>   "renditions": [
>       {
>         "audioOnly": false,
>         "controllerType": "DEFAULT",
>         "displayName": "Space-Galaxy.mp4",
>         "encodingRate": 800000,
>         "frameHeight": 360,
>         "frameWidth": 640,
>         "id": 1520959065001,
>         "referenceId": null,
>         "remoteStreamName": null,
>         "remoteUrl": null,
>         "size": 1829449,
>         "uploadTimestampMillis": 1332267195355,
>         "url": "rtmp://brightcove.fcod.llnwd.net/a500/e1/uds/rtmp/ondemand/&mp4:57838016001/57838016001_1520959065001_Space-Galaxy.mp4&1460095200000&a99dcabb0f88cdf8d21b3a5778da8e06",
>         "videoCodec": "H264",
>         "videoContainer": "MP4",
>         "videoDuration": 20000
>       },
>       {
>         "audioOnly": false,
>         "controllerType": "DEFAULT",
>         "displayName": "Space-Galaxy.mp4",
>         "encodingRate": 1800000,
>         "frameHeight": 720,
>         "frameWidth": 1280,
>         "id": 1520962209001,
>         "referenceId": null,
>         "remoteStreamName": null,
>         "remoteUrl": null,
>         "size": 4265519,
>         "uploadTimestampMillis": 1332267361480,
>         "url": "rtmp://brightcove.fcod.llnwd.net/a500/e1/uds/rtmp/ondemand/&mp4:57838016001/57838016001_1520962209001_Space-Galaxy.mp4&1460095200000&a99dcabb0f88cdf8d21b3a5778da8e06",
>         "videoCodec": "H264",
>         "videoContainer": "MP4",
>         "videoDuration": 20000
>       },
>       {
>         "audioOnly": false,
>         "controllerType": "DEFAULT",
>         "displayName": "Space-Galaxy.mp4",
>         "encodingRate": 1200000,
>         "frameHeight": 404,
>         "frameWidth": 720,
>         "id": 1520962169001,
>         "referenceId": null,
>         "remoteStreamName": null,
>         "remoteUrl": null,
>         "size": 2777863,
>         "uploadTimestampMillis": 1332267330633,
>         "url": "rtmp://brightcove.fcod.llnwd.net/a500/e1/uds/rtmp/ondemand/&mp4:57838016001/57838016001_1520962169001_Space-Galaxy.mp4&1460095200000&a99dcabb0f88cdf8d21b3a5778da8e06",
>         "videoCodec": "H264",
>         "videoContainer": "MP4",
>         "videoDuration": 20000
>       },
>       {
>         "audioOnly": false,
>         "controllerType": "DEFAULT",
>         "displayName": "Space-Galaxy.mp4",
>         "encodingRate": 314758,
>         "frameHeight": 224,
>         "frameWidth": 400,
>         "id": 1520959023001,
>         "referenceId": null,
>         "remoteStreamName": null,
>         "remoteUrl": null,
>         "size": 690193,
>         "uploadTimestampMillis": 1332267165343,
>         "url": "rtmp://brightcove.fcod.llnwd.net/a500/e1/uds/rtmp/ondemand/&mp4:57838016001/57838016001_1520959023001_Space-Galaxy.mp4&1460095200000&a99dcabb0f88cdf8d21b3a5778da8e06",
>         "videoCodec": "H264",
>         "videoContainer": "MP4",
>         "videoDuration": 20000
>       },
>       {
>         "audioOnly": false,
>         "controllerType": "DEFAULT",
>         "displayName": "Space-Galaxy.mp4",
>         "encodingRate": 500000,
>         "frameHeight": 268,
>         "frameWidth": 480,
>         "id": 1520916807001,
>         "referenceId": null,
>         "remoteStreamName": null,
>         "remoteUrl": null,
>         "size": 1126642,
>         "uploadTimestampMillis": 1332265138822,
>         "url": "rtmp://brightcove.fcod.llnwd.net/a500/e1/uds/rtmp/ondemand/&mp4:57838016001/57838016001_1520916807001_Space-Galaxy.mp4&1460095200000&a99dcabb0f88cdf8d21b3a5778da8e06",
>         "videoCodec": "H264",
>         "videoContainer": "MP4",
>         "videoDuration": 20000
>       },
>       {
>         "audioOnly": false,
>         "controllerType": "DEFAULT",
>         "displayName": "Space-Galaxy.mp4",
>         "encodingRate": 129761,
>         "frameHeight": 224,
>         "frameWidth": 400,
>         "id": 1520953533001,
>         "referenceId": null,
>         "remoteStreamName": null,
>         "remoteUrl": null,
>         "size": 227983,
>         "uploadTimestampMillis": 1332266955420,
>         "url": "rtmp://brightcove.fcod.llnwd.net/a500/e1/uds/rtmp/ondemand/&mp4:57838016001/57838016001_1520953533001_Space-Galaxy.mp4&1460095200000&a99dcabb0f88cdf8d21b3a5778da8e06",
>         "videoCodec": "H264",
>         "videoContainer": "MP4",
>         "videoDuration": 20134
>       }   ],   "FLVFullLength": {
>       "audioOnly": false,
>       "controllerType": "DEFAULT",
>       "displayName": "Space-Galaxy.mp4",
>       "encodingRate": 500000,
>       "frameHeight": 268,
>       "frameWidth": 480,
>       "id": 1520916807001,
>       "referenceId": null,
>       "remoteStreamName": null,
>       "remoteUrl": null,
>       "size": 1126642,
>       "uploadTimestampMillis": 1332265138822,
>       "url": "rtmp://brightcove.fcod.llnwd.net/a500/e1/uds/rtmp/ondemand/&mp4:57838016001/57838016001_1520916807001_Space-Galaxy.mp4&1460095200000&a99dcabb0f88cdf8d21b3a5778da8e06",
>       "videoCodec": "H264",
>       "videoContainer": "MP4",
>       "videoDuration": 20000   },   "videoFullLength": {
>       "audioOnly": false,
>       "controllerType": "DEFAULT",
>       "displayName": "Space-Galaxy.mp4",
>       "encodingRate": 500000,
>       "frameHeight": 268,
>       "frameWidth": 480,
>       "id": 1520916807001,
>       "referenceId": null,
>       "remoteStreamName": null,
>       "remoteUrl": null,
>       "size": 1126642,
>       "uploadTimestampMillis": 1332265138822,
>       "url": "rtmp://brightcove.fcod.llnwd.net/a500/e1/uds/rtmp/ondemand/&mp4:57838016001/57838016001_1520916807001_Space-Galaxy.mp4&1460095200000&a99dcabb0f88cdf8d21b3a5778da8e06",
>       "videoCodec": "H264",
>       "videoContainer": "MP4",
>       "videoDuration": 20000   } }

It has some links like

rtmp://brightcove.fcod.llnwd.net/a500/e1/uds/rtmp/ondemand/&mp4:57838016001/57838016001_1520959023001_Space-Galaxy.mp4&1460095200000&a99dcabb0f88cdf8d21b3a5778da8e06

but there are not playing any thing on MediaPlayer. May be because of `rtmp` and for `rmtp` I may have to use Vitamio but I can't as I am restricted to use native MediaPlayer.

On IOS I am able to get the urls using :  `BCOVPlaybackService`  But there is no such class in android .

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay This is how I am getting URL

```
 EventEmitter eventEmitter = player.getEventEmitter();
            Catalog catalog = new Catalog(eventEmitter, account, privacy);
            catalog.findVideoByID(video_brightcove_id, new VideoListener() {
                @Override
                public void onVideo(Video video) {

                    Map<DeliveryType, SourceCollection> map = video.getSourceCollections();
                    Set<DeliveryType> st = map.keySet();
                    SourceCollection sor = map.get(DeliveryType.valueOf("MP4"));
                    Set<Source> se = sor.getSources();
                    Object[] ar = se.toArray();
                    Source hp = (Source) ar[0];
                    Map<String, Object> ma = hp.getProperties();
                    String url = (String) ma.get("url");
               ////this is the video url 

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(String s) {

                    Log.e("Error ", s);
                }
            });
```

Thanks :)

Comment: What will be the case of DRM protected contents? Will it also contains delivery type as MP4

Comment: not sure about the cause but yes it contains delivery type as MP4.